# merge two associative arrays add titles

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

I have two arrays

```
$Array_1 = array(
    'ID_1' => 'Michael', 
    'ID_2' => 'Jerry', 
    'ID_3' => 'Tony', 
    'ID_4' => 'Roger',
);

$Array_2 = array(
    'ID_1' => 'Chef', 
    'ID_2' => 'Mechanic',
    'ID_3' => 'Cook', 
    'ID_4' => 'Dealer',
);
```

I wish to merge them on the ID column and have my final array be in this form

```
$employees = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Jason',
        'occupation' => 'Chef'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Mike',
        'occupation' => 'Mechanic'
    ),
    ...
);
```

I know I can array combine them like below:

```
$new_array = array_combine(array_values($Array_1), array_values($Array_2));
```

but how would I add the titles "Name": and "Occupation":

Comment: Just write a loop, really nothing fancy about it.

Comment: Please, provide your arrays structure as they are in PHP - we can't guess if your ids are keys of array, or they are just key of arrays inside your array

Comment: the ids are keys of the array

Comment: @Yoshi yes I am aware I can use a loop to through the new array after combination and add headers I was wondering if there is a more concise way to do it

Comment: @Edward still unclear. Is it `[['ID'=>'ID_1', 'Name'=>'Jason'], [...]]` or `['ID_1'=>'Jason', ...]` ?

Comment: @almaDO sorry I hope this is a bit clearer http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tuj-ri9

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the correct array structures based on your phpfiddle

Comment: Are both arrays sorted by key and do all keys exist between the two arrays?

Comment: @jack Arrays are not sorted, but they will always be of equal length (there will always be something for every ID_x in both arrays even if it's just a blank)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2**
Aah, now I see the phpfiddle in the comments and the edit to the OP. So, the ID is already the key of the array? ... Then just do

```
foreach($Array_1 as $key_1 => $value_1) {
    $new_Array[$key_1]['Names'] = $Array_1['Names'];
}
foreach($Array_2 as $key_2 => $value_2) {
    $new_Array[$key_2]['Occupation'] = $Array_2['Occupation'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this,

```
  $Employees = array();
  foreach($Array_1 as $key=>$value):   
    $Employees['Employees'][] =  array('Name'=>$value, 'Occupation'=>$Array_2[$key]);
  endforeach;

  echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Employees);
  echo "</pre>";

  echo json_encode($Employees);
```

OP:

```
 {"Employees":[{"Name":"Jason","Occupation":"Chef"}, {"Name":"Mike","Occupation":"Mechanic"}]}
```

Comment: This is a pretty awesome solution

Comment: This approach assumes that the order of both Arrays are guaranteed the same for the ID's. Don't count on it!

Comment: @nl-x Only the order of `$array_1` matters here.

Comment: @Jack As per the edit of the OP, indeed, the order doesn't matter. But this answer totally loses the ID/key. So still, though it's short, I find it too flawed.

Comment: @nl-x the ID is stored in the database so losing it here is trivial but you are correct it does. I think your solution is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 3):

i dont know how the array look. but you can try my two solution

First solution

```
$array1 = array("id" => array("id1", "id2", "id3"), "names" => array("name1", "name2", "name3"));
$array2 = array("id" => array("id1", "id2", "id3"), "occupation" => array("occupation1", "occupation2", "occupation3"));
$filter_array = array("employees" => array());
foreach ($array1["id"] as $index => $key) {
    $employee = array();
    $occupation = in_array($key, $array2["id"]) ? $array2["occupation"][$index] : false;
    if ($occupation === false) {
        continue;
    }
    $employee["name"] = $key;
    $employee["occupation"] = $occupation;
    array_push($filter_array["employees"], $employee);
}
echo "<pre>" . print_r($filter_array, true) . "</pre>";
```

Second Solution

```
$array1 = array("id1" => array("names" => "name1"), "id2" => array("names" => "name2"), "id3" => array("names" => "name3"));
$array2 = array("id1" => array("occupation" => "occupation1"), "id2" => array("occupation" => "occupation2"), "id3" => array("occupation" => "occupation3"));
$filter_array = array("employees" => array());
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $employee = array();
    if (!isset($array2[$key])) {
        continue;
    }
    $employee["name"] = $value["names"];
    $employee["occupation"] = $array2[$key]["occupation"];
    array_push($filter_array["employees"], $employee);
}

echo "<pre>" . print_r($filter_array, true) . "</pre>";
```

i hope my code can help.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
$Array_1 = array(
    'ID_1' => 'Michael', 
    'ID_2' => 'Jerry', 
    'ID_3' => 'Tony', 
    'ID_4' => 'Roger',
);

$Array_2 = array(
    'ID_1' => 'Chef', 
    'ID_2' => 'Mechanic',
    'ID_3' => 'Cook', 
    'ID_4' => 'Dealer',
);
$filter_array = array("employees" => array());
foreach($Array_1 as $key => $value){
    $employee = array();
    if(!isset($Array_2[$key])){ continue; }
    $employee["name"] = $value;
    $employee["occupation"] = $Array_2[$key];
     array_push($filter_array["employees"], $employee);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/array_walk) . It runs a function per each array item .combine them in the function .

Comment: No. Because with same success I can say 'use PHP'. This is SO. It's not for fast answers. Be more specific.